# Kuberentes RBAC rule to allow creating Jobs only from a CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rbac

Is it possible to create a kubernetes RBAC rule that allows creating a Job from an existing CronJob, but prevents creating a Job any other way?

We want to keep our clusters tightly locked down to avoid arbitrary deployments not managed by CICD - but we also need to facilitate manual testing of CronJobs, or rerunning failed jobs off schedule. I'd like developers to be able to run a command like:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-job my-job-test-run-1
```

But not be able to run something like:

```
kubectl create job my-evil-job -f evil-job.yaml
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Which kubernetes version do you use? Since there are some changes introduced all the time. Which account the developers are using? Like user ones or SA for apps

Comment: We're currently using v1.21 on EKS and we map developers to the `view` cluster role. Only the devops team and the CICD pipelines have write access at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario in order to successfully execute this command:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/<cronjob_name>
```

User/ServiceAccount should have proper [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) rules (at least two from the output provided below, create `Jobs` and get `CronJobs`.

In first example I granted access to create `Jobs` and get `CronJobs` and I was able to create `Job` and `Job --from CronJob`

```
user@minikube:~$ cat test_role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: job
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["create"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["cronjobs"]
  verbs: ["get"]
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --image=inginx testjob20
job.batch/testjob20 created
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --from=cronjobs/hello testjob21
job.batch/testjob21 created
```

But if I granted access only to create `Job` without get `CronJob`, I was be able to create `Job` but not to create `Job --from CronJob`

```
user@minikube:~$ cat test_role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: job
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["create"]
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --image=nginx testjob3
job.batch/testjob3 created
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --from=cronjobs/hello testjob4
Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch "hello" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:t1" cannot get resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"
```

When I deleted access to create `Jobs`, I couldn't create `Job` and also `Job --from CronJob`

```
user@minikube:~$ cat test_role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: job
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["cronjobs"]
  verbs: ["get"]
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --image=inginx testjob10
error: failed to create job: jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:t1" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"  
user@minikube:~$ kubectl create job --from=cronjobs/hello testjob11
error: failed to create job: jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:t1" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"
```

As you can see if User/ServiceAccount doesn't have both permission in this scenario it's impossible to create (`Job` or `Job --from CronJob`) so it's impossible to create such restrictions using only RABC rules.

One possible solution is to split this permission into two different User/ServiceAccount for two different tasks (first user can create `Jobs` + get `CronJobs`, second user without permission to create `Jobs`).

Another possibility is to try to use k8s admission Controller with f.e. [Open Policy agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/v0.12.2/kubernetes-admission-control/)

Comment: OPA is the best solution